Error with GTM no-script and Nextjs App router
I'm switching from the pages router to the app router in Nextjs and I'm facing a problem that doesn't give me to much information: Minified React error #329 - Unknown root exit status. When I try to load some of the pages that I have already in the app router randomly I get only the content of the fallback that I have in the page Suspense component until I click somewhere and the UI gets refreshed.
So far I only know is that the error only happens when I add (importing a component) the GTM noscript with an iframe in the layout file.
Currently my layout and GTM files are defined as client component.
I only get the error in production mode with the build, I have tried to add the component inside a Suspense component but I get the same error.
This is what I'm trying to add and gives me that strange behavior.
Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated
<noscript>
  <iframe
    src={``}
    height="0"
    width="0"
    style={{ display: "none", visibility: "hidden" }}
  />
</noscript>


I finally found the problem, I was adding the noscript tag outside the  and that was causing the issue, moving it to the right place was the solution.
